# Error callback always firing even when successful on the server

Tags: javascript, ajax, api, rest, flask

I'm learning REST API with Python flask and JavaScript.

I've created the API successfully but whenever I try calling it with Ajax or JavaScript it fails but on the flask server it shows the 200 response.

My flask code:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)

tasks = [
    {
        'id': 1,
        'title': u'Buy groceries',
        'description': u'Milk, Cheese, Pizza, Fruit, Tylenol', 
        'done': False
    },
    {
        'id': 2,
        'title': u'Learn Python',
        'description': u'Need to find a good Python tutorial on the web', 
        'done': False
    }
]

@app.route('/todo/api/v1.0/tasks', methods=['GET'])
def get_tasks():
    return jsonify({'tasks': tasks})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Html Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Api Learn</title>
    <script src="js/jQuery.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bulma/bulma.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
</head>
<body>
    <section class="section">
        <button id="fetch" class="button is-link is-large">Click</button>
    </section>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript code:

```
const baseUrl = "http://127.0.0.1:5000/todo/api/v1.0/tasks";


$("document").ready(function() {
    $("#fetch").click(function() {
        fetch(baseUrl)
        .then(function(data) {
            console.log(data)
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            console.log(error)
        })

    })
});
```

Error message on console:

```
stack:TypeError: Failed to fetch
message:Failed to fetch
```

But successful on flask backend:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [01/May/2021 20:03:51] "GET /todo/api/v1.0/tasks HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Whenever I called it with curl it's always successful:

```
$ curl -i "http://localhost:5000/todo/api/v1.0/tasks"
```

The curl response:

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 317
Server: Werkzeug/1.0.1 Python/3.9.4
Date: Sat, 01 May 2021 19:06:23 GMT

{
  "tasks": [                                    {
      "description": "Milk, Cheese, Pizza, Fruit, Tylenol",
      "done": false,
      "id": 1,
      "title": "Buy groceries"
    },                                          {
      "description": "Need to find a good Python tutorial on the web",
      "done": false,
      "id": 2,
      "title": "Learn Python"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Backend successfully sends JSON response but the fetch promise is failing because of the access control origin. Usually if you serve the HTML code using flask jinja then you won't face the problem. This is happening because HTML is serve from different way.

Please add this code below to check if the access control is the real issue.

```
response =  jsonify({'tasks': tasks})
response.headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
return response
```

There is a corps package in flask ecosystem that you can use to easily solve those cors related issues. [flask-cors](https://flask-cors.readthedocs.io/en/latest)